# 2-loop correction to renormalized operator in $\phi^4$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

I have a particular question with respect to renormalized operators of $\phi^4$ theory, namely the mass operator $\phi^2$ but at two-loop order. With respect to Peskin and Schroeder's text, chapter 12, the normalization is given by equation 12.113 while the first loop correction is equation 12.114, repeated here for clarification
\begin{equation}
\text{1-loop} = \frac{i^2}{p^2q^2}\int \frac{d^Dr}{(2\pi)^D}(-i\lambda)\frac{i}{r^2}\frac{i}{(k+r)^2}. \tag{12.114}
\end{equation}
Now, my question is, what does the 2-loop equation look like, or mainly how to set it up since we are in $\lambda\phi^4/4!$ theory, but the vertices in the diagram in equation 12.114 has me a little confused since one vertex has 3 propagators while another has 4.

My guess for the two loop equation is to just stack another loop on top of the first so it looks like a regular 2-loop calculation for the self-energy but with different external momentum legs. But then there should be one more diagram when it comes to the 2-loop order corrections, namely one that looks like the self-energy sunset diagram but with one more external leg attached.

Any kind of reference or just direct answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you may want to check my [notes on qft](https://hepnotes.files.wordpress.com/2021/11/qft-miscellaneous-topics-1.pdf) pages 621 and more.

Comment: @Oбжорoв So I am not doing two-loop renormalization using old perturbation theory, but I am instead computing $\langle [\phi]_\mu[\phi]_\mu\rangle$ where $\mu$ is our mass scale, not an index which we can set at $\mu = |p|$. So what I want to compute is then $\langle \phi(p)\phi(q)\phi^2(k)\rangle$ to two loop order with $[\phi]_\mu = (Z(\mu)^{1/2}\phi$ is the renormalized operator.